# Allocated data of NSMutableRequest object's body not being released

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, xcode-instruments

In my app I have to perform a multipart POST request. In the request I have to send a file that is stored in the device's photo Library. After it is finished uploading and received the returned data, I send the request a release message, but Instruments shows me the data persists in the device's memory.

This is how I create the request object:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];

[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";

// set Content-Type in HTTP header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

// post body
NSMutableData *body = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

// add parts (all parts are strings) `parts` is a NSDictionary object
for(id key in parts) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [parts objectForKey:key]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

// add files data - `file` is a ALAssetRepresentation object
NSData *fileData;
NSString *filename = [file filename];
Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(file.size);
NSUInteger buffered = [file getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:file.size error:nil];
fileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];




if (fileData) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    if ([requestType isEqualToString:PUBLISH_TYPE_VC_MANDA]) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachment\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    } else {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
    [body appendData:fileData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[fileData release];


[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

[body release];

// set the content-length
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"Keep-Alive" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];

// set URL `adress` is a NSURL object
[request setURL:address];

//set cookie
if (storedCookie) {

    NSDictionary *properties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[storedCookie name], NSHTTPCookieName, myDomain, NSHTTPCookieDomain,@"/",NSHTTPCookiePath, [storedCookie value], NSHTTPCookieValue, nil];

    NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:properties];
    NSArray* cookies = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: cookie, nil];
    NSDictionary * headers = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:cookies];
    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
}
```

After this, and after I received the response, i perform `[request release]` but the allocated bytes stay in memory.

I ran `Instruments` in the Allocations mode, and it is claiming that there is an object of category `Malloc 91MB` (the size of the ALAsset I'm uploading). By looking at the Call tree, the Symbol that's taking up all the memory is `[NSConcreteMutableData appendBytes:length:]` inside the method described above.

Why isn't it freeing the bytes ? And more importantly, why does it have to move the data to the device's memory ? I've seen apps like Facebook upload very large videos from the gallery without any memory problems.

Thank you very much for your attention, any help or directions would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT:** Further investigation showed me that when I use `[request release]` the request object is released, but it's body isn't. Pretty weird behaviour...

**EDIT2:** I explicitly used `[request.HTTPBody release];` and the bytes were released. I still cannot believe that `[request release]` wasn't freeing it's body. Could this be a bug ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using ARC?

Comment: I personally would have loved to use ARC, but the owner specified that we must not use it

Comment: Why?  Compatibility isn't even a good reason anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Your request has a `retainCount` of 2:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]; // 1
```

...

```
[request retain]; // 2
```

Then if you do `[request release]`, it's decreased by one.

The solution is not to do `[request retain]`.

Comment: I completely agree with you. I removed the retain, but still the memory isn't being freed. Any ideas ?

Comment: You also forgot to invoke `free(buffer);`.

Comment: The Apple documentation says that `freeWhenDone:YES` should take care of that

Comment: No problem my friend, I am really very thankful for your help. See my edits in the question, I figured out what was happening

Comment: Note that the absolute retainCount is irrelevant;  it may or may not be what @kovpass claims (and likely won't be as soon as the URL is used in a request).  The key is that you have to *balance retains with releases* before an object will be deallocated.

Comment: I agree, in fact it wasn't. That's why I edited my original question and added more details to it. If you are curious to find out what was causing the memory to not release, please refer to it

Answer (score 0):

After further investigating, the memory wasn't being released because the request's property `HTTPBody` needed to manually be released (see my second edit).

As to sending large chunks of data in a `NSRequest`, there is an easier way that won't consume the device's memory. You have to write the file to the disk, and then map it. I have described it in details in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16169779/1341626). Hope it helps someone