# How to send NSData To Server

Tags: ios, web-services, nsurl

How to post nsdata of size around 500 Mb-1GB to NSURLRequest, My Services are not accepting Chunks, While I am trying to post am getting Timeout error even i set my timeouts to 200 seconds also, could anyone please suggest me.... Thanks in advance

Comment: possible solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961534/uploading-large-nsdata-to-the-web

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042360/nsdata-and-uploading-images-via-post-in-ios

Comment: Isn't it a bad idea anyway if you can't receive chunks for such huge files from a mobile device?

Comment: Wow. That's a lot of data to transfer from a mobile device. What is it you are transferring?

Comment: I am trying to send Image/video files,Please suggest me i am working from couple of days on this issue

Comment: I got the solution to upload a lot of date. Thanks for your suggestions